# What is the part of speech of 'up' in the following sentence?

Tags: parts-of-speech

This is from [a news article](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/04/28/business/economy/inflation-fed-wages-prices.html).

> Consumer prices *were* **up** 4.2 percent in March from a year earlier,
> according to the Fed’s preferred measure of inflation, the Personal
> Consumption Expenditures index, the Commerce Department said Friday.

I looked up 'up' in [the Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/up#dictionary-entry-1).

> adverb 3d. : to or at a greater speed, rate, or amount
>
> adjective 2b : being above a former or normal level (as of quantity or
> intensity)

I think here '**up**' might be an adverb if '*were*' is an intransitive complete verb and an adjective if '*were*', a linking verb.

I wonder what part of speech '**up**' is in the above quote.

Comment: "Up" is a preposition in your example.

Comment: @BillJ Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, "up" describes the noun "prices", so it's an adjective meaning "higher".

Further, without the phrase "4.2 percent" the meaning of "up" doesn't change, so it appears "4.2 percent" is an adverbial phrase modifying the degree to which the prices are "up", perhaps with an elided "by".

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: I appreciate the checkmark, but BillJ knows a lot and he commented that it's a preposition, so it's worth waiting to see if his argument is more convincing than mine.

Comment: As far as I know, an adverb can modify other adverbs. So is there any possibility that an adverbial phrase  '(by) 4.2 percent' is modifying an adverb 'up' which means 'at  a greater amount'?

Comment: An adverb can modify adjectives, verb, other adverbs, and entire clauses. In this case, "up" cannot be an adverb because it modifies a noun, so it's an adjective. It's only an adverb if you argue it modifies the verb "were", which makes no sense to me as "were" is a *copula* here.

Comment: I understand. 'up' in 'prices went up' is an adverb as taken as an example in the Merriam-Webster dictionary and 'up' in 'prices were up' is an adjective as seen here. Am I right? Thank you very much.

Comment: Exactly. In "*Prices went up*", the word "up" is modifying how the prices *went*, which means it's modifying a verb, so it's an adverb.